# Yeoman Gruntfile.js - add a vendors directory to the dist build

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have this current dist organization :

[image]

I want this one :

[image]

As you can see I want my dist vendors files `vendor.sha.js` and `oldieshim.sha.js` in a directory `vendors`. How should I do this in the Angular Yeoman Gruntfile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a night to think of it.
Just had to learn how HTML blocks works with the Grunt-usemin.
So needed to customize that in my HTML :

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js --> TO : `<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendors/oldieshim.js -->`
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js --> TO : `<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendors/vendor.js -->`
```